# How to translate a ternary relationship to SQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have 3 entities in my database:

- Client
- Project
- Contract

The principle is very simple,  a client establishes a contract for a specific project.
a project can only be assigned to a client.
a contract can only be assigned to a unique combination of client and project.

what is an efficient and clear way to translate this into SQL tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be a 3 tables

1. A table with all your clients where the primary key is some sort of unique id.
2. A table with you projects where the primary key is some sort of unique id.
3. A table with your contracts where the primary key is some sort of unique id.

The projects table will need client_id column which is a foreign key to the clients table.
The contracts table will need a project_id column which is a foreign key to the projects table.